# getting 404 error using jQuery.Ajax in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jquery

In my google apps engine application, I'm trying to get data from an XML file using jquery.Ajax but when I run the page, it returns a 404 error for the XML file. The XML file is in the root folder of the application i.e. on the same level as the index page.

I have an index page and in the index page, I have the code below (within a script tag)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "states.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    error:function(xhr,err){
       alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status);
       alert("responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
    },              
    success: function(xml) {
       alert("success");
    }
  });
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a static file handler defined in your app.yaml? If all you've done is placed the XML file in the application root, it will not be automatically routable.

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Static_File_Handlers